# Nodes with the same parent not respecting order

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I have a binary tree build with `vis.js`. On server side I build a js that will insert the new nodes on node select events.

This is the problematic layout
[image]

This is the intended layout
[image]

As you can see in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/NicosKaralis/7334407291e7787a884c4735ed0b3ce3) the script that generates the tree of the wrong layout is the same as the correct layout, with just one extra node.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

P.S.: This is not a "chance problem", if this happens with a given root element, it will always happen

Comment: Dear @YakovL , I think you didn't read the entire question. I offered a MCV example. In the gist is all I am using to build both of the graphs

Comment: Yes, I can see that. The problematic bits are: 1) your example doesn't seem to be minimal – the gist is quite long and I'm sure you can throw away a number of lines while keeping the issue reproducible; 2) the code should be in the question itself, not only on a third-party resource (these are guidelines that can be found in the help section, too. As a person that perhaps can help you, I'm mostly interested the the first bit.